# When will a new Raspberry Pi be released?

Tags: hardware, pi-2

I know the Raspberry Pi 2 has been released very recently, but are we likely to see a new model with more features within the next year? And is it likely the Raspberry Pi Foundation will ever produce a really powerful Pi with killer Ethernet, USB 3.0 ports, more RAM and a faster CPU?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The RPi Foundation didn't give us much of a heads up when the RPi 2 came out, but I think some people were expecting it.

As far as the killer specs go, it's rather unlikely.  In fact, we've gotten a resounding ["no"](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=74695&p=535407) for USB 3.  The RPi isn't meant to be a "killer" device.  It's primary purposes are to be inexpensive, and educational.  The more features/power you add to the board, the more power it will consume (bad for embeded things), the more it will heat up (bad for embeded things) and the more it will cost (bad for educational things).

If you want a high power embeddable board, I suggest you check out some more powerful alternatives like the banana pi, beaglebone black, pandaboard, Intel NUC, etc.

Comment: Adding to this: Rumor has it that the rPi came out partially because of [Odroid's C1 invasion](http://www.hardkernel.com/main/products/prdt_info.php?g_code=G141578608433) of rPi's turf and partially because the original Pi was too slow for certain educational uses. I can attest to both as I use rPi's in an educational setting and running [Code.org](http://www.code.org) was painful and slow, and I ordered a C1 to try out as a replacement, but dropped that route as soon as the rPi2 came out.

Comment: @PhilB. That makes sense... There's a lot of things the original RPi could barely do, even with a modest overclock.  I'm very happy with the RPi 2 though!